# Win10 tablet cannot ping RPi anymore

Tags: raspbian, windows, ping

I have run into something seriously weird. It used to work and then from one day to the next it has stopped working.

My Setup:
- Stream 7 Tablet with Win10
- Raspberry Pi Model 2B with Vilros plug and play Wlan dongle

What I did in the past:

1. On Win10 tablet:

   a. netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=adhocname key=password

   b. netsh wlan start hostednetwork

   c. Then I simply waited until the RPi automatically connected

   d. ping the RPi: ping raspberrypi.mshome.net

   e. ....ssh into the pi

but now for some reason when I try ping the pi it returns either;

- request timed out
  OR
- Reply from 169.254.155.200: Destination net unreachable

anyone got any ideas please? NOTE Windows firewall is turned off completely. Not sure, but that didnt make a difference in the past.

Why would it work perfectly fine the one day yet the next not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried shutting everything down including the router. Then bring them up one at a time with router being first then the devices? Could be a lease issue maybe?

Comment: I am not using a router. I am connecting the pi directly to the tablet. And yep, Ive shut down everything too. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, didn't see a mention that it was direct device to device.

Answer (score 1):

Right so one solution I have found is to rollback or format the tablet completely. (keep your files though)

There were one or two internet security packages I installed and then subsequently uninstalled. I think they are what caused the change somewhere somehow.

So if you do run into the same issue, yay for you, just format, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too simple an answer, but have you checked that it's still on the same ip?

Comment: how do you mean? the IP on the tablet is left floating. I have tried changing it to that of the pi's (excl last digit ofc), once connected, but no luck. I havent changed any ip settings on the pi itself. But pinging "raspberrypi.mshome.net" should take care of assigned ip's on the pi, should it not?

Comment: Do a network discovery to find the actual IP of the Pi, as it is expected to change every time it connects to the wifi.

Comment: The ip of the pi was not the issue. I tried using the actual ip too, but as said, if the actual ip does not work then "ping raspberrypi.mshome.net" will not work either and visa versa. Check my above solution